# How to calculate 105% of close in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to pine script and I'm trying to create entry condition for tradingview when

1. SMA and bar crosses above for long & below for short
2. Bar which crosses SMA is green for long and red for short
3. 2nd Bar after Bar crosses SMA is green for long and red for short
4. Open position based on 105% of bars from step 2 for long and 95% for short

I cannot figure out how to do step 4. I've tried many different ways to do so, but nothing seems to be working for me.

```
//@version=4

point=close[1]*1.05
point1=close[1]*0.95
 
condition_long = crossover(close[1],sma1) and close[1]>open[1] and close[0]>open[0] and  close[0]==point
condition_short = crossunder(low[1],sma1) and close[1]<open[1] and close[0]<open[0] and close[0]==point1

strategy.entry("Long Condition", strategy.long, 100, when=condition_long) 
strategy.entry("Short Condition", strategy.short, 100, when=condition_short) 

strategy.exit("Exit", "Long Condition", profit = 1, loss = 0.5)
strategy.exit("Exit", "Short Condition", profit = 0.1, loss = 0.5)
```

Comment: The weakness of Pine is revealed when you want to debug your code. I suggest you to read about Labels and create a small code that can draw a label above a bar (keep in mind that the number of labels is limited to 500) and write a character for each conditional into the label. You can use `"\n"` string to put new lines into the labels. This way you can check which conditional is true on a bar and which are false (probably one of the 4 is always false). So if `crossover(close[1],sma1)` is true, you put an "◆" into a string, and if false, you put "◇" into it. Repeat this for all conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Drey, your entry criteria is very specific, so I have decided to exclude it from an example that shows you how to "set and save" your stop and limit 1) based on trade direction bias, 2) so it does not recalculate on each bar. To combat 2), we use the "var" operator. This will hold the value we assign to it. We then assign it conditionally if we meet our entry criteria, and are not already in a trade of that bias. Here is the example below:

```
var stop  = 0.0
var limit = 0.0

point=close*1.05
point1=close*0.95

if condition_long and not (strategy.position_size > 0)
    stop  := point1
    limit := point

if condition_short and not (strategy.position_size < 0)
    stop  := point
    limit := point1
 
strategy.exit("Exit", stop= stop, limit= limit, when= strategy.position_size != 0)
```

Cheers and best of luck in your trading and coding